# jRadioButton value in jTable

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, jradiobutton

I have just begun to learn Java. I seem to be stuck on a particular thing I would like Java to do for me.

I would like to have two jRadioButtons working together with a jTable. jRadioButton 1 should display "Yes" while jRadioButton 2 should display "No".

All I get, however, is a type of an error message when trying to add row to my jtable.

Instead of my radiobuttons displaying "yes/no", they display "javax.swing.JToggleButton$ToggleButtonModel@2a93a9f2". Any ideas what this 'error message' means? I have googled but cannot find a thing about it. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
I added this string:

```
public String Tapp;
```

My radiobuttons:

```
    private void jRadioButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
Tapp = "Yes";
}

private void jRadioButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                              
Tapp = "No";
}
```

and on the "Add" button for my jtable I have this.
My buttongroup is called "bgButtonGroup".

```
    private void bAdd11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    ErrorMessage.setText("");
    DefaultTableModel model3;
    model3 = (DefaultTableModel) tblProduct11.getModel();
    if(!tfChassi.getText().trim().equals("")){
        model3.addRow(new Object[]{
            tf1.getText(),
            tf2.getText(),
            tf3.getText(),
            cb1.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb2.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb3.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb4.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            tf4.getText(),
            tf5.getText(),
            bgButtonGroup.getSelection()});
```

Comment: You need to create a cell renderer for this. Look at [here](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/RadioButtonTableExample.htm)

Comment: @rdonuk I don't want the actual button inside the jtable, i just want the text of "Yes" or "No" inside the column. I add data using jcomboboxes, textfields and eventually...jradiobuttons... is this renderer thing still relevant? Thanks for your reply.

Comment: I don't think I understand your issue. Please share some code.

Comment: When I click either of the RadioButtons, and add a new row to the jTable, I want the ButtonGroup to display Text in the jTable, either Yes or No depending on what RadioButton you clicked. As I said, all I get is that errormessage. I'm not sure on how to achieve this so really; My question is, how do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bgButtonGroup.getSelection()` this is returning the model of the selected radio button, not the text of it. If you set action command to your radio buttons you can get the text by `bgButtonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand()`. For example after create your `yesRadioButton` set "yes" as action command for it with `yesRadioButton.setActionCommand("Yes")`.

```
private void bAdd11ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                       
    ErrorMessage.setText("");
    DefaultTableModel model3;
    model3 = (DefaultTableModel) tblProduct11.getModel();
    if(!tfChassi.getText().trim().equals("")){
        model3.addRow(new Object[]{
            tf1.getText(),
            tf2.getText(),
            tf3.getText(),
            cb1.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb2.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb3.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            cb4.getSelectedItem().toString(),
            tf4.getText(),
            tf5.getText(),
            bgButtonGroup.getSelection().getActionCommand()
        }
    );
```

Comment: What can I say...? It worked perfectly. Thank you so much for your kindness in helping a silly noob like myself. You did my weekend, @rdonuk! :))